# How do I get Steam Workshop mods working for the GOG version of Project Zomboid?

Tags: mods, gog, project-zomboid

I own the GOG version of *Project Zomboid* Build 41.53, and I'd like to use the mods from the Steam Workshop. How do I safely go about this, and what do I have to do to get them working?

Comment: Since the two are different architechtures, I would first try my luck at adding the game to steam as an 'outside sourced game', maybe it will let you. If that doesnt work, the mods are probably available somewhere else, like NexusMods.

Comment: @Fredy31 Some of the mods are published at different places by the modders - like NexusMod or their webpage - unfortunately, that is a tiny number of mods. Usually I reach out to the modders and ask them, which sometimes works out, but often not.

Comment: Yeah and I fully expect steam to not let you do the first suggestion. Like oh, you bought it outside our infrastructure? So sad... seems you wont be able to use our services for the mods. So my best guess will be that you will have to use Nexus Vortex or install all of them manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find the mod at the [Project Zomboid Steam Workshop](https://steamcommunity.com/app/108600/workshop/) and then copy its webpage URL from your browser's address bar.
2. Open the site: http://steamworkshop.download/*  and paste the URL, e.g., https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2368058459
   <sub>(*Any site or method that can allow you to download Steam Workshop mods should also work, like the SteamCMD method described at: https://www.gog.com/forum/rimworld/guide_how_to_download_mods_directly_from_steam)</sub>
3. Download the mod.
4. Open the downloaded .ZIP file.
5. Inside the .ZIP file, copy or extract the directory named `mods`, to the directory at `%USERPROFILE%\Zomboid` or `C:\Users\USER_NAME\Zomboid`.
6. Open the game. Turn on the mod in the mods submenu.

<sup>Intructions modified from: [The Indie Stone forums post: *Tutorial - how install mods from Steam Workshop when you have game on GOG*](https://theindiestone.com/forums/index.php?/topic/34793-tutorial-how-install-mods-from-steam-workshop-when-you-have-game-on-gog/) (replaced the non-working site with another site that works, and added info)</sup>